# JQuery is not working properly when embeded into a ASP.NET WebForm project

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I'm just using a simple `slideToggle` function of jQuery. It works properly in my HTML file. But whenever I take codes into a ASP.NET WebForm project, script doesn't work. I can't achieve slide effect.

Is this a known issue? It's probably a popular mistake done by developers though. What could be the problem? Any possibilities?

(I didn't copy&paste any code because of I thought this is not a specific situation, but I can show codes if you want)

Comment: Please do show code, it's *probably* IDs not being what you're used to when they get rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is due to the unpredictable IDs of ASP.NET elements; there *is* fixed naming available in 4.0 (`ClientID`) - try using that with your `#foo` selectors? (where `ClientID` is set to `"foo"`)

Comment: Isn't unpredicable a bit hard since you can programatically get the real ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a class on the html element rather than using the id and update your selector to use the class.